# Implementing Bidirectional A* Shortest Path Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, bidirectional

I am implementing a symmetric bidirectional A* shortest path algorithm, as mentioned in [[Goldberg and Harrelson,2005]](http://msr-waypoint.com/pubs/154937/soda05.pdf).  This is only for understanding the algorithm, therefore I used the most basic version without any optimization steps.

My problem is the bidirectional algorithm appears to scan almost two times the number of edges scanned in a uni-directional A* search on the test graph.

**Example:** a s-t query on a road network using A* (left) and bidirectional A* (right). Nodes scanned by the forward and backward search are colored in red and green, respectively.  The heuristic function is simply the euclidean distance to t or s. The computed paths (blue) are correct in both figures.

[image: A* search example]

I may be understanding the algorithm logic incorrectly. Here is how I adapted unidirectional A* to bidirectional (from reference)

- Alternate between forward search and backward search. Maintain variable `mu` as the current best estimate of s-t path length.
- In the forward search, if `w` in edge `(v,w)` has been scanned by the backward search, do not update w's labels.
- Each time a forward search scan `(v,w)` and if `w` has been scanned by the reverse search, update `mu` if `dist(s,v) + len(v,w)+dist(w,t)<= mu`
- Stopping condition:  when forward search is about to scan a vertex `v` with `dist(s,v) + potential_backward(v) >= mu`
- (Similar rules apply in the backward search)

*I'd appreciate if anyone can point out the flaws in my implementation, or some more detailed explanation of the bidirectional A* algorithm.*

Code in Python:

```
""" 
bidirectional_a_star: bidirectional A* search 

g: input graph (networkx object)
s, t: source and destination nodes
pi_forward, pi_backward: forward and backward potential function values
wt_attr: attribute name to be used as edge weight 
"""

def bidirectional_a_star(g,s,t,pi_forward, pi_backward, wt_attr='weight' ):
    # initialization 
    gRev = g.reverse() # reverse graph        
    ds =   { v:float('inf') for v in g } # best distances from s or t
    dt = ds.copy()
    ds[s]=0
    dt[t]=0  
    parents = {} # predecessors in forward/backward search
    parentt = {}
    pqueues =[(ds[s]+pi_forward[s],s)]  # priority queues for forward/backward search
    pqueuet = [(dt[t]+pi_backward[t],t)]

    mu = float('inf') # best s-t distance

    scanned_forward=set() # set of scanned vertices in forward/backward search
    scanned_backward=set()

    while (len(pqueues)>0 and len(pqueuet)>0):
        # forward search
        (priority_s,vs) = heappop(pqueues) # vs: first node in forward queue

        if (priority_s >= mu): # stop condition
            break

        for w in g.neighbors(vs): # scan outgoing edges from vs
            newDist = ds[vs] + g.edge[vs][w][wt_attr]            

            if (ds[w] > newDist and w not in scanned_backward):                
                ds[w] = newDist  # update w's label
                parents[w] = vs
                heappush(pqueues, (ds[w]+pi_forward[w] , w) )

            if ( (w in scanned_backward) and  (newDist + dt[w]<mu)):
                 mu = newDist+dt[w]

        scanned_forward.add(vs)  # mark vs as "scanned" 

        # backward search
        (priority_t,vt) = heappop(pqueuet) # vt: first node in backward queue

        if (priority_t>= mu ):  
            break

        for w in gRev.neighbors(vt): 
            newDist = dt[vt] + gRev.edge[vt][w][wt_attr]

            if (dt[w] >= newDist and w not in scanned_forward):
                if (dt[w] ==newDist and parentt[vt] < w):
                    continue
                else:
                    dt[w] = newDist
                    parentt[w] = vt
                    heappush(pqueuet,(dt[w]+pi_backward[w],w))
            if ( w in scanned_forward and  newDist + ds[w]<= mu):
                 mu = newDist+dt[w]

        scanned_backward.add(vt)

    # compute s-t distance and shortest path
    scanned = scanned_s.intersection(scanned_t)    
    minPathLen = min( [ ds[v]+dt[v] for v in scanned ] ) # find s-t distance   
    minPath = reconstructPath(ds,dt,parents,parentt,scanned) # join s-v and v-t path

    return (minPathLen, minPath)
```

---

**Update**

Following [Janne's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624035/implementing-bidirectional-a-shortest-path-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment53268347_32624035), I created a [demo](https://github.com/yang2011/p2p_demo) that tests the search on a few examples. The implementation has been improved, and fewer nodes are scanned.

**Example:** Shortest path from the red dot to the green dot on a (directed) grid graph. The middle figure highlights nodes scanned by A*;  The right figure shows nodes scanned by the forward search (orange) and those scanned by the backward search (blue)
[image: toy example]

However, on the road network, the union of nodes scanned by the forward search and those scanned by the backward search is still more than the number of nodes scanned by a unidirectional search. Perhaps this depends on the input graph?

Comment: How are you logging/recording visited edges?

Comment: The algorithm adds labels on vertices rather than edges. e.g. I used `scanned_forward` and `scanned_backward` to store scanned /settled vertices. I also store the predecessor of every node on the two shortest path trees in `parents` and `parentt`. Distances to source or destination of those nodes are stored in `ds` and `dt`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your issues, but your initialization of `ds` and `dt` (`ds = dt =  { v:float('inf') for v in g }`) makes them both references to the same dictionary.

Comment: thanks for spotting that, but in fact I only wrote them in one instruction to save space for posting. In the original code, variables are initialized separately. I will change that in my question

Comment: Have you tested with a small graph? Could you post a runnable example including small and simple data?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I posted a runnable demo

Answer (score -3):

Hy, Your problem is that, you don't put the right condition to stop, the stop condition is when (forward and backward search are meet),